# Почему не подключаются css стили Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, веб-программирование

Создал Django проект, html страницу прогружает, а css ни в какую

Подключение в HTML файле:
 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css'%}" type="text/css">`

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main/Minecraft_site.html')
```

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Структура папок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что выводит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: структуры проекта нет. Где у вас лежат `css` файлы в проекте? Использовали что то такое: `py manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: css лежит в `\Minecraftserver\main\static\style`
html лежит в `\main\templates\main`
Не использовал, сейчас попробую

Comment: Так у вас вообще нет папки css получается. А вы к ней пытаетесь обращаться

Comment: Ого, переименовал папку и все получилось, спасибо вам)

Comment: `urls.py`, https://google.com/?q=django+serve+static